# What is the correct for loop code that traverses the neighbors of a matrix element and checks bounds?

Tags: for-loop, matrix, language-agnostic

I can't seem to figure out an elegant way to do this, but I know I have seen it in the past. I just don't know what to search for.

I am given the row and column indices, `r` and `c` of a 2-D matrix. I want to be able to traverse the 4 neighbors. If the element is at a corner, it will only have 2 neighbors. If the element is at the boundary, but not a corner, it will have 3 neighbors. If it's interior it will have 4 neighbors.

So I want to traverse `(r+1,c)`, `(r-1,c)`, `(r,c+1)`, `(r,c-1)` and perform the bounds check `r >= 0 && r < num_rows` and `c >= 0 && c < num_cols` simultaneously in a double nested for loop.

The only thing I was able to come up with is this:

```
vector<vector<int>> adds{{0,1},{1,0},{-1,0},{0,-1}}

for(int i = 0; i < adds.size(); i++)
{
  //do bounds checking with r + adds[i][0] and c + adds[i][1]
  //do something with matrix[r + adds[i][0]][c + adds[i][1]]

}
```

The particularly elegant one I remember seeing did something with a max function and didn't use the `adds` array that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Complex numbers! :D

```c++
Complex i = {0, 1};

int neighbours[4];
// Multiplying by i to rotate 90 degrees
for (int i = 0, Complex offset = {1,0}; i < 4; ++i, offset *= i) {
  if (x + offset.re >= width or x + offset.re < 0 or y + offset.im >= length) 
    neighbours[i] = nullptr; // Some known invalid value
  else
    neighbours[i] = arr[x + offset.re][y + offset.im];
}
```

Here is one of my [implementations](https://github.com/Uchiha-Senju/practicals/blob/master/half_yearly_practical_scripts/ques_2-snail_the_matrix.cpp).

A cool thing is that if you change the angle the multiplier represents(`{cos(phi), sin(phi)}`) you could get the cells of a matrix making, say, a hexagon around it! You can even change the distance they are from the main cell, or the rotation of the entire thing.

[image i can't post yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NDuz.png)